# Convert rows in MariaDB to json array

Tags: sql, arrays, json, mariadb

I tried to run this SQL in MariaDB - 10.4.22-MariaDB:

```
SELECT CONCAT( '[', GROUP_CONCAT( JSON_ARRAY( name ) ), ']' ) FROM `mytable`;
```

But I'll get this:

```
[["ith1,"],["ith2"],..]
```

I need to get it without the brackets for each ithem, so I'll get just basic array:

```
["ith1,","ith2",..]
```

I also tried to use just `GROUP_CONCAT`, but if the separator is also in text, the whole array is then broken.

Example data:

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Football, boys "first group" |
| 2 | Football, girls "first group" |
| 3 | Streetball |

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add some data examples ?

Comment: @ErgestBasha added

Comment: Use `JSON_ARRAYAGG()`.

Comment: @Barmar I'm using old version of MariaDB. JSON_ARRAYAGG() was unfortunately added in MariaDB 10.5.0. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_arrayagg/

Comment: I edited to make it clear this is MariaDB, not MySQL. MariaDB forked from MySQL a long time ago, and it should not be considered as a compatible product anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`JSON_QUOTE()`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_quote/) in `GROUP_CONCAT()`

```
SELECT CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_QUOTE(name)), ']') FROM test3;
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=00073b44491ba562da11cec4991692c4)